What does target.settableVariables property do in a YAML pipeline step and what is its use case?
Introduction
In Azure YAML pipelines there are two categories of variables:

Compile-time variables: those you create using the variables keyword in the YAML file.
Runtime variables (Output variables): those you create in scripts using the logging commands syntax.

My assumptions on these is as the following:

Compile-time variables have fixed values and can't be overridden at queue or runtime.
Output variables are not defined anywhere else outside the task that defines them.
Output variables have a SINGLE purpose, that is to be used in downstream tasks or jobs. They have NO purpose or meaning to the script itself because the script will use its own syntax for variables to use internally (unless the name of the output variable is dynamically generated and taken from a script variable. Example, Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$variableName]value")

Question
Based on the assumptions above, I am struggling to understand the use case of target.settableVariables property in a YAML pipeline step. Why do I need to block a variable from being outputted (to downstream jobs and tasks) if its sole purpose is to be outputted to downstream jobs and tasks? Why don't I simply not create it?
The documentation provides the following example:
steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce;]crushed tomatoes"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secretSauce;]crushed tomatoes with garlic"
    target:
     settableVariables:
      - sauce
    name: SetVars
  - bash: 
      echo "Sauce is $(sauce)"
      echo "secretSauce is $(secretSauce)"
    name: OutputVars

So (question), what's the use case of secretSauce in here?
Note: there is a decent lack of knowledge on my part. For example, I don't even know what the description of target.settableVariables property even mean:

Restrictions on which variables that can be set by a step.

I thought output variables can only be created and set by a step (script, pwsh, bash, etc.) So, why bother creating it in the first place if I am going to block it? The documentation example could be rewritten (according to my confused logic) as such:
steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce;]crushed tomatoes"
    name: SetVars
  - bash: 
      echo "Sauce is $(sauce)"
    name: OutputVars

And if I really need that variable then I don't block it, I simply make it issecret.
Thanks ahead.

Logging command SetVariable can be used to initialize or modify the value of an existing variable:
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce;]crushed tomatoes" 

Given that steps can accidentally or maliciously modify another step's variable (and consequently changing future steps' behavior), you can prevent such situations by:

Using target.settableVariables OR
Using read-only
variables

Example 1 - using target.settableVariables
variables:
  - name: sauce # <------------------ variable sauce defined here
    value: amatriciana

  - name: secretSauce # <------------------ variable secretSauce defined here
    value: pesto

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - bash: |

      # Variable can be modified because it is configured as 'settable'
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce;]crushed tomatoes" 

      # Generates warning. Variable cannot be modified because it is NOT configured as 'settable'
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secretSauce;]crushed tomatoes with garlic"
    target:
      settableVariables:
        - sauce
    name: SetVars
  - bash: 
      echo "Sauce is $(sauce)"

      echo "secretSauce is $(secretSauce)" # <------------------ vOutput: secretSauce is pesto
    name: OutputVars

Running the pipeline:


Example 2 - using readonly variables:
variables:
  - name: sauce
    value: amatriciana

  - name: secretSauce # <------------------ variable secretSauce defined here as readonly
    value: pesto
    readonly: true

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - bash: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce;]crushed tomatoes" 

      # Generates error. read-only variables cannot be modified
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secretSauce;]crushed tomatoes with garlic"
    name: SetVars

Running the pipeline:


Thank you. This explains how it works but I still don't understand its use case other than perhaps as a self-check not to set this variable in the given step? Because as a YAML author, I don't need to "tell" the task not to set a variable. If my task doesn't need to or shouldn't modify an existing variable, I simply author it not to. And it is unlikely someone else will update the task to block setting a variable without either breaking the task (and brings us back to the point whether we need to modify the variable in this task or not) or updating the task so it doesn't modify the variable.

The target.settableVariables property controls which variables a step can set, providing a way to prevent inadvertent overwrites.
This is useful in complex pipelines where common template scripts or tasks may set variables that are not needed.
For example, in the YAML below, I use the Bash task to execute a bash file called test.sh. By using the target.settableVariables property, I can ensure that my variables remain unchanged by the content within the bash task. As the author of the YAML, you might focus on the YAML content, but changes to test.sh could go unnoticed. That's why this property exists.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
  - name: sauce  
    value: amatriciana
  - name: secretSauce 
    value: pesto

steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      filePath: 'test.sh'
    name: SetVars
    target:
      settableVariables: none
  - bash: 
      echo "Sauce is $(sauce)"
      echo "secretSauce is $(secretSauce)" 
    name: OutputVars

test.sh:
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce;]crushed tomatoes"

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secretSauce;]crushed tomatoes with garlic"

Result:

